# Postgres column type unknown

Tags: postgresql, migration

I am trying to port a database where there is a table with a column of type `unknown`. pg_restore raised the error

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  column "color" has pseudo-type unknown`.

I don't understand why such tables can exist given that the doc says

> A pseudo-type cannot be used as a column data type

However, I want to keep the database as it is and do not do any modifications. Which error code should I specify to catch this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be a dump from an old PostgreSQL database where it was still possible to generate `unknown` columns.

The best thing would be to fix the source database, but if you cannot do that, generate an SQL script from the dump with `pg_restore` and fix the column definitions there.

Comment: The old server is running on postgres 9.0, and the new one is running on version 10.8. However, I did not find `unknown` listed in pseudo-types in the [doc of version 9.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/datatype-pseudo.html).

Comment: In addition, the doc of 9.0 also says "A pseudo-type cannot be used as a column data type"

Comment: `unknown` became a pseudo-type with [commit d8d32d9a5](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=d8d32d9a56a3cecfb14e8f47ebd50b780edffe60). Creation of tables with `unknown` columns was disabled in [commit 1e7c4bb004](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=1e7c4bb0049732ece651d993d03bb6772e5d281a). Both commits were in January 2017, long after 9.0.